# How to mirror html files and it's accompanying images locally with wget with specified filenames?

Tags: python, html, ruby, bash, wget

I need to grab a url as html along with it's accompanying images.  The html is to be saved with a custom filename (I'm giving it a timestamp in the calling script) and the images need to have these timestamps as well.

The resultant folder should should be structured like:

```
2012-02-22 06:00:00 UTC.html
2012-02-22 07:00:00 UTC.html
2012-02-22 08:00:00 UTC.html
img1_2012-02-22 06:00:00 UTC.gif
img2_2012-02-22 06:00:00 UTC.gif
img1_2012-02-22 07:00:00 UTC.gif
img2_2012-02-22 07:00:00 UTC.gif
img1_2012-02-22 08:00:00 UTC.gif
img2_2012-02-22 08:00:00 UTC.gif
```

Essentially this is a mirror that needs to rewrite the images paths for the local relative path in the html.  I've played around with wget's `--directory-prefix` and `--output-document` with no real success obviously since it embeds the images in the html output file.

Is this doable with stock wget or is it better to write my own script to just pull each file down and then parse up the html file replacing the strings appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to what you are trying to accomplish [here](https://github.com/serv/4chanImageGroper). I'm pretty sure you can reengineer what I got there to create your program.

Check out [4chan_image_crawler.rb](https://github.com/serv/4chanImageGroper/blob/master/4chan_image_crawler.rb)

The program does these things.

- Given a URL (a thread URL of 4chan.org/b/), create a string value containing entire html file of the URL.
- With some regex manipulation, put all the relevant images URL into an array called **occurances**.
- The html string contains duplicates of image links. So just clean up the duplicates and save the final image URL links into array called **result**.
- For all the entries in result array, save the images into /images folder within the current directory.

Let me know if you have trouble understanding my code.

The key to doing this successfully is knowing how to manipulate regex and using **scan** from the String class in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, you've done essentially what I was leaning towards.  Obviously not exactly the same as my scenario, but close. I don't think wget or the like is flexible enough per se and by the time you get done with all the customization and groping the html output for filenames, you end up having been better off just writing a script to pull it all out and store it as you wanted in the first place.  Plus you have the advantage of full control.